# Preserving "\label" in the final PDF to retrieve it with poppler?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf

Our PDF contains lots of `\label{foo}` commands, where we jump to from links from within the PDF (using the *hyperlinks* package)

When I tried to jump to there from within our PDF displaying application, which uses the [Poppler](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/) library, I however failed to find that label.

```
// C++ code to find the label 'foo' in the document
Poppler::LinkDestination *linkDest = m_doc->linkDestination("foo");
```

When I instead tried to use the `\hyperdef` command, I was able to do what I wanted

```
\hyperdef{foo}{bar}{}
```

Doing in our PDF application

```
Poppler::LinkDestination *linkDest = m_doc->linkDestination("foo.bar");
```

Can anyone please explain the technical difference between these commands? We would like to be able to keep using `\label` if possible, since we have a large LaTex codebase that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2012/07/28 v6.82u package `hyperref` provides option `destlabel` for this purpose.

Comment: For the time being until we update, I just use `\hyperdef` and the other form of `\hyperref` like `\hyperref{}{cat}{name}{}`. I just couldn't find whether an empty URL is allowed, but it works! :)